# Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'SignupPage' (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, types, properties, mean-stack

Hello nice fellows from stackoverflow!

I'm new to MEAN stack, and still trying to get into the basics of it.

I'm trying to make a simple authentication. This is the code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Auth } from '../../providers/auth';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  selector: 'signup-page',
  templateUrl: 'signup-page.html'
})
export class SignupPage {

  role: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: Auth, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

  }

  register(){

    this.showLoader();

    let details = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        role: this.role
    };

    this.authService.createAccount(details).then((result) => {
      this.loading.dismiss();
      console.log(result);
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    }, (err) => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
    });

  }

  showLoader(){

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Authenticating...'
    });

    this.loading.present();

  }

}
```

And this is the error i get:

```
[12:43:17]  typescript: src/pages/signup-page/signup-page.ts, line: 31 
            Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'SignupPage'. 

      L30:  this.authService.createAccount(details).then((result) => {
      L31:    this.loading.dismiss();
      L32:    console.log(result);

[12:43:17]  typescript: src/pages/signup-page/signup-page.ts, line: 35 
            Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'SignupPage'. 

      L34:  }, (err) => {
      L35:      this.loading.dismiss();
      L36:  });

[12:43:17]  typescript: src/pages/signup-page/signup-page.ts, line: 42 
            Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'SignupPage'. 

      L42:  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      L43:    content: 'Authenticating...'

[12:43:17]  typescript: src/pages/signup-page/signup-page.ts, line: 46 
            Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'SignupPage'. 

      L46:  this.loading.present();

[12:43:17]  transpile failed
```

Anyone can clarify me what i'm missing and what should i study to proceed with my project?

Comment: maybe you need to define a property named loading in the SignupPage class?

Comment: well.. it looks like there's a typo or mistake in it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```js
export class SignupPage {

  role: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  loading: any; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: Auth, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

  }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `showLoader()` method. You are doing:

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: 'Authenticating...'
});

this.loading.present();
```

This may be legal code in plain javascript, but typescript is complaining because you haven't defined a `loading` property in your class. Just define the property like:

```
export class SignupPage {

  role: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  loading: LoadingController; //I'm assuming that's the correct type

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public authService: Auth, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {

  }
....
}
```

Comment: Im still missing the basics on how to implement this. How should i proceed?